# Just a general question about localization and degree of freedom

Tags: robot-localization

I am currently utilizing a localization library built for ros. As my robot does not have capability to move like quad-copter in 3D space it gave me an idea about limiting its localization to 2D space.

My general question is:

1. Is it an acceptable practice to fix orientation output by setting roll and pitch to be zero (flat) all the time?
2. Also, is it acceptable to fix the covariance of said roll and pitch to be very low?

Thanks for anyone's time for reading this. And if this is a duplicate of another question, it would be very helpful if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ROS package, Robot Localization, has a setting for 2d, and the roll and pitch are set always at zero. It works fine for a robot on a flat (or mostly flat) surface.